# Sending an http response with Json content using marshallers in Akka Http

Tags: json, scala, marshalling, akka-http, argonaut

I want to send a Http error response with a message in JSON format in the body. I am having trouble using the [PredefinedToResponseMarshallers](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.0.4/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/marshalling/PredefinedToResponseMarshallers.scala).

I saw an implementation in the [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.4/scala/http/common/marshalling.html#using-marshallers) but I tried a similar thing and it throws a compilation error.

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.Marshal
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.{ Marshaller, ToResponseMarshaller } 

trait Sample extends Marshallers with Directives { 
     def login(user: Login): CRIX[HttpResponse] = {
        for {
          verification ← verify(user)
          resp = if (verification) {
            HttpResponse(NoContent, headers = Seq(
              .........
            ))
          }//below is my http Error response
          else Marshal(401 → "It is an Unauthorized Request".asJson).to[HttpResponse]
        } yield resp
      }
    }
```

It gives this compilation error :

```
Sample.scala:164: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Object
[error]  required: akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
[error]     } yield resp
[error]             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (http/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I have just started Akka Http so forgive me if it is trivially easy.

TL;DR: I want(examples) to learn how to use ToResponseMarshallers in Akka Http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `to[HttpResponse]` of negative condition takes on `Future[HttpResponse]`. At the same time positive condition returns `HttpResponse`.

Try something like (I assume `verify` takes on `Future[T]`):

```
for {
  verification <- verify(user)
  resp <- if (verification) 
           Future.successful(HttpResponse(NoContent, headers = Seq(.........)) )
         else 
           Marshal(401 → "It is an Unauthorized Request".asJson).to[HttpResponse]
} yield resp
```